# Loop over specific sheets and put values properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate some values from specific columns in Sheet1 and Sheet2. The problem is that the Sub below first correctly calculates the numbers from a matrix in Sheet1. It puts the matrix in some cells on Sheet1. And then the code rewrites that matrix with the numbers from Sheet2. But I want to put the calculations from Sheet2 on Sheet2, not Sheet1. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong? Best Regards!

```
Sub Try()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastOne As Long
    Dim Sheetz As Variant

    Sheetz = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    For h = LBound(Sheetz) To UBound(Sheetz)

        With Worksheets(Sheetz(h))

            numbers = Array(1, 2, 3)

            For j = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
                For i = 1 To 3
                    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                    LastValue = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Value
                    FirstOne = .Cells(LastRow - j, i).Value
                    Cells(i + 1, j + 5) = LastValue / FirstOne - 1
                Next i
            Next j
        End With
    Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like your assignment, `Cells(i + 1, j + 5) = ...` is unqualified. This should do the trick: `.Cells(i + i, j + 5) = LastValue / FirstOne - 1`

Comment: @DanWagner Great. ´ws.Cells´ also works:)